# Can I disable "-t" option from docker image

Tags: docker, security, command-line-interface

we would like to put a docker image into our client's internet off machine.

To prevent the possible code leak (python script) in some level, my idea would be to make an image that only leave specific port open and write socket programs to pass command/data.

Before I put it into practice, I need to make sure user cannot access the running container using other method, include the "-t" option.

So as a newbie, I would like to ask if this is possible. Thanks a lot!

Comment: There is little hope to achieve what you want. There are even easier ways to copy files out of a container, have a look at the `docker cp` sub-command.

Comment: @henry would there be ways to prevent this...... thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No: a Docker image has no way to prevent (or require) any specific runtime options.

In the particular case of trying to hide the contents of a Docker image, anyone who can run any `docker` command at all can trivially get unlimited root access on the host, and can `docker run` any command; even without being able to use the `-t` option they can `docker run ... tar cvf - /app` to copy the source out, or they can probably find the source code in the `/var/lib/docker` tree with some poking around.

The only way to prevent interactive shell access to a container is to not have a shell in the image at all (and even then, you could bind-mount a Busybox binary into the container and run that).  The only way to prevent source code from being copied out of an image is for it to not be there at all.  This means you have to use a compiled language (Go, C++, Java, Rust) if this is a concern for you.